# How to apply decorators to the label provider in RCP eclipse environment?

Tags: java, eclipse-rcp

I wanted to apply decorators (that is images) to my custom label provider which is of tree viewer form displaying the list of some folder names. I googled it out but unfortunately only i got the information of how to create decorators.

For example : i have a label provider by name "ViewLabelProvider" which is able to display list of folders. I want to differentiate these folders by applying some icons through decorators, but I am  not able to establish a relationship between the custom decorators to the above label provider mentioned.

Please let me know, how to achieve this.

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Are you using the `org.eclipse.ui.decorators` extension point or something else?

Comment: Why using `getImage()` method of label provider is not an option?

Comment: @ Greg: yes I am using that extension point and created my custom decorator. But the decorate() api is not at all getting called.I am using IlightWeightDecorator interface

Comment: @Alexander: I am using the getImage api of label provider for getting the folder image. Based on certain condition these folders should have specific icons on them. Because of that I went for using custom decorators

Comment: May be you could create set of folder images, combined with required decorators and then just select appropriate image in getImage method, instead of trying to decorate those?

Comment: Yes Alexander I will try with what you have said. The advantage of using extension point decorators was that it take care of disposing all the images and also the UI performance gets increased as there is a separate thread provided by that extension instead of using the same UI thread.

Answer (score 2):

The tree label provider needs to be `DecoratingLabelProvider` to pick up the decorators:

```
treeViewer.setLabelProvider(
      new DecoratingLabelProvider(your label provider,
                PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getDecoratorManager().getLabelDecorator()));
```

you pass your label provider as a parameter to `DecoratingLabelProvider`.